# Need to submit Add to Cart form with jQuery / without AJAX /

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I am having some trouble submitting the data from add to cart.

Basically i have this function / which prevents the user from buying the product without filling the form /:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        var productID = $(".single-product-page").attr('id');
        var productIDstr = productID.replace(/product-/g,'');
        console.log(productIDstr);
        if($("#tmcp_textfield_1").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_2").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_3").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_4").val() == "" ||
        $("#tmcp_textfield_5").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_6").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_7").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_8").val() == "" ||
        $("#tmcp_textfield_10").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_11").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_12").val() == "" ||
        $("#tmcp_textfield_13").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textarea_14").val() == "" || $('#tmcp_choice_14_0_15').prop('checked') != true ) {
            $('.tm-section-link')[0].click();

        }
```

And after all of these are done i have put :

```
   else {    
            $('form.cart').submit();
        }
```

but that only refreshes the page, without actually adding the product to the cart. I just need to submit the data after that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: No I had to rebuild it...

Answer (score 0):

You should add for example hidden input to the form before sending the form.

```
    $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar'
}).appendTo('form');
```

But it is the only example. You need to fit it to existing code

Comment: not sure how will that help me? can you clarify please

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
.trigger('click');
```

**Note:**

your code is saying if all of those fields are empty, trigger the click. If you want it to NOT submit if those fields are empty, you may want to change it to `!=` instead of `==`

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $addToCartButton = $(this);
  var productID = $(".single-product-page").attr('id');
  var productIDstr = productID.replace(/product-/g,'');

  if($("#tmcp_textfield_1").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_2").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_3").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_4").val() == "" ||
     $("#tmcp_textfield_5").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_6").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_7").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_8").val() == "" ||
     $("#tmcp_textfield_10").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_11").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textfield_12").val() == "" ||
     $("#tmcp_textfield_13").val() == "" || $("#tmcp_textarea_14").val() == "" || $('#tmcp_choice_14_0_15').prop('checked') != true ) {
            $addToCartButton.trigger('click');

  }
```